# How do I plot the lines in different graphs?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

How do I plot the lines in different graphs?

I've created 9 plots while all the lines are being drawn in the last one.

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(17.7,8.27)})
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 3,ncols=3)
for i in range(0,9):
    df1 = df[df['UID'] == df['UID'].unique()[i]]
    df1 = df1[['BaselineHalf','rateadj_amount_usd']]
    df1 = df1.set_index('BaselineHalf')
    plt.plot(df1)
```

Comment: have you tried `plt.show()` ?

Comment: Use `plt.subplot(3,3,i+1)` in your loop, just before your line `plt.plot(df1)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your subplots via `axs[row,col].plot(df1)`.
So you you could for example iterate over them using:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(17.7,8.27)})
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 3,ncols=3)
idx=[(row,col) for row in range(0,3) for col in range(0,3)]
for i, tup in enumerate(idx):
    df1 = df[df['UID'] == df['UID'].unique()[i]]
    df1 = df1[['BaselineHalf','rateadj_amount_usd']]
    df1 = df1.set_index('BaselineHalf')
    axs[tup[0],tup[1]].plot(df1)
```